# Error 429: Insufficient tokens (DefaultGroupUSER-100s) What defines a user?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

*tl/dr do 100 devices all using the same Client ID count as 100 users, with their own limits, or one user sharing limits?*

I have a webpage which reads and writes to a Google Sheet.

Because the webpage needs to know if a cell has changed, it polls the server once every 1000ms:

```
var pollProcId = window.setInterval(pollForInput, 1000);
```

where `pollForInput` does a single:

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request).then(callback);
```

When I tried to use this app with a class of 100 students I got many `429` error codes (more than I got successful reads) in response to `google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues` requests:

[image: Error code 429-a-thon]

Many of my users never got as far as seeing even the first request come back.

As far as I can make out, these are `AnalyticsDefaultGroupUSER-100s` errors which, according to [the error responses page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors):

> Indicates that the **requests per 100 seconds per user per project** quota
>   has been exhausted.

But with my app only requesting once per 1000 milliseconds, I wouldn't expect to see this many `429`s as I have a limit of 100 requests per 100 seconds (1 per second) so only users whose application didn't complete in 100 seconds should have received a `429`.

I know I should implement Exponential Backoff (which I'll do, I promise) but I'm worried I'm misunderstanding what a "user" in this context is.

Each user is using their own device (so presumably has a different IP address) but they are all using my "Client ID".

Does this scenario count as many users making one request per second, or a single user making a hundred requests per second?

Comment: I've just found [this](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7035610?hl=en&ref_topic=7013279) which suggests my requests should have a unique identifier, either `userIp` or `quotaUser`, neither of which I'm including. Could this be relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the **user** in the `per user quota` means that a single user making a request. So let's take the Sheets API, it has a quota of `100` for the `Read requests per 100 seconds per user`. So meaning only a single user can make a request per second. Note that Read request has a same set of quota as the Write request. But these two sets of quotas have their own set of quota and didn't share the same limit quota.

If you want a higher quota than the default, then you can apply for a higher quota by using this [form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScq7tc9q9hoQvvYmLh70q0udES386vg7eZExI2IbwmQCJMQYQ/viewform) or by visiting your developer console, then click the pencil icon in the quota that you want to increase.

I also suggest you to do the **Exponential Backoff** as soon as possible, because it can help you to avoid getting this kind of error.

Hope it helps you.